# COM+: NotImplementedException

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit, com+, notimplementedexception

I'm trying to instaniate my own COM+ component (running as a library application) without success.

All I get is a NotImplementedException when I try to create it

```
dim myComponent As New MyComponent()
```

The stack trace is not of much help:

```
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    
   at System.EnterpriseServices.Thunk.Proxy.CoCreateObject(Type serverType, Boolean bQuerySCInfo, Boolean& bIsAnotherProcess, String& uri)    
   at System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponentProxyAttribute.CreateInstance(Type serverType)    
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)    
   at MyApp.MyMethod() in D:\blabla\MyService.asmx.vb:line 66 (this line have been modified by me)
```

The COM+ component is compiled for "AnyCPU" and the webbservice is running x64 inside ASP.Net 4 Application pool.

HRResult: -2147467263

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not removed the old .tlb files (for a previous version). Removing them helped.